# self-extracting archive using powershell and base64

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a tar file and I would like to base64 encode it, and somehow put all of it inside of the same powershell script that I will use to unencode the tar file back into a real tar file again?

Any ideas on how to do that?

The application for doing this would be to send a non-powershell script file to a remote machine.  Example:

```
invoke-command -FilePath ./selfextracting.ps1 -Computer remotecomputer
```

Output:

```
Now running ./selfextracting.ps1 on remotecomputer.
Powershell script is self-extracting `myfiles.tar` embedded inside 
the script ./selfextracting.ps1 into 
the remote directory C:/User/dude/mystuff:
.....
.....
....
....
done.
```

I've seen this trick done with Bash script many years ago, but never with powershell...

Comment: See the question I tagged this as duplicating. It's an EXE not an archive but the same general process for encoding and decoding the file to and from base64 still applies.

Comment: It should be doable at least.  For an explained bash version: cf. here https://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818